# what is wrong with this c# code?

Tags: c#

Please tell me whats wrong with this c# code..

```
public bool CloseCOMPort()
    {
        try
        {
            bool isClosed = false;
            if (oSerialPortMisc != null && oSerialPortMisc.IsOpen)
            {
                oSerialPortMisc.Close();
                isClosed=true;

            }
            else
            {
                isClosed = false;

            }
            return isClosed;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

        }
    }
```

When I compile this code it gives error.. "not all code paths return a value".
I dont know whts wrong here. PLease help.. 
Thanxxx...:)

Comment: What error message do you get? What are you trying to do?

Comment: perhaps you could evaluate on what wrong part's you would like to find in it?

Comment: What kinds of errors are you receiving? Are there any exceptions being thrown? Is there a behavior that is not what you're anticipating? Are you trying to use this code concurrently? Some more information will help provide a more clear answer in this situation I suspect.

Comment: you've swallowed an exception - which is "BAD PRACTICE" and then not returned anything

Comment: When there's an exception you don't return a value or rethrow the exception. By doing one of these compiler should accept the code

Comment: What do you expect your code to do? What does it/doesn't it do to make you think it is wrong? The empty catch block is not good practice.

Comment: I would never return a value from within a try-catch. Best stick your return outside of this so that you can properly catch any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be more specific. Each fork in your code must either return an appropriate value or throw, if the method isn't a void. In your case, the catch fork doesn't do any of the above, and your code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 8):

The method doesn't always return a value. <strike>Your compiler should've told you the same thing.</strike>

A value(`isClosed`) is only returned within the `try { .. }` block. Now, imagine if something fails(throws an exception) before it gets to the return statement, the code will continue in the `catch { .. }` which doesn't return anything, this is why your code fails to compile.

You should place a `return` statement at the bottom of your method.

Define the `isClosed` at the top of your method and return it at the bottom regardless.

```
public bool CloseCOMPort()
{
    bool isClosed = false;

    try { .. }
    catch { .. }

    return isClosed;
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, if the code gets in the catch block it wont return anything.

Comment: @himanshu: It didn't say that earlier on :). Anyway, I explained what happens if your code goes in to the `catch` block.

Answer (score 4):

your method have to specify a return value in every case.
try:

```
public bool CloseCOMPort()
{
    bool isClosed = false;

    try
    {
        if (oSerialPortMisc != null && oSerialPortMisc.IsOpen)
        {
            oSerialPortMisc.Close();
            isClosed=true;
        }
        else
        {
            isClosed = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
    }

    return isClosed;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If an exception is raised then the method won't return a value.

Move the declaration of `isClosed` outside the `try` block and add:

```
finally
{
    return isClosed;
}
```

You can also simplify your code to:

```
public bool CloseCOMPort()
{
    bool isClosed = false;
    try
    {
        if (oSerialPortMisc != null && oSerialPortMisc.IsOpen)
        {
            oSerialPortMisc.Close();
            isClosed = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        // Add some logging of the exception here
    }
    finally
    {
        return isClosed;
    }
}
```

It's also bad practice to catch the base `Exception`. You should only catch the exceptions thrown by the methods you call.

Using the `finally` block ensures that the code is executed even if you decide to rethrow any exceptions you trap, or decide not to trap the exceptions at all.

Comment: +1: Of all the answers, this is the only one that actually _handles_ the caught exception in some way.  (Even if it's just a comment suggesting that the OP handle it.  The first thing I noticed in the question wasn't the lack of a return in the `catch`, it was the lack of _anything_ in the `catch`.

Answer (score 3):

There's no return statement in/after the catch.

Try this:

```
public bool CloseCOMPort()
    {
        try
        {
            bool isClosed = false;
            if (oSerialPortMisc != null && oSerialPortMisc.IsOpen)
            {
                oSerialPortMisc.Close();
                isClosed=true;

            }
            else
            {
                isClosed = false;

            }
            return isClosed;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
        return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

u must always return a boolean try this :

```
public bool CloseCOMPort()
{
    bool isClosed = false;
    try
    {

        if (oSerialPortMisc != null && oSerialPortMisc.IsOpen)
        {
            oSerialPortMisc.Close();
            isClosed=true;

        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {

    }

    return isClosed;
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily. He can throw from the catch and the code is still good. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility your could drop into your `try`/`catch` block in the event of an expection.

This would mean that yoru function would never return a value. The C# compiler is clever enough to spot this.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `isClosed` inside the try block and not returning anything in the catch block. So, if any exception is raised, your function will not return anything.

Suggestion: You can return `false` on the catch block.